# Batch correct Latex PDF's with wrong encoding to correct umlauts

Tags: pdf, unicode, pdfpages

at my university the template everyone uses seems to use the standard ot1 encoding. This leads to all umlauts to be correctly displayed but if copied they turn into two characters. Ex. Makro¨okonomik, Ph¨anomene,¨Uberpr¨ufung,

Is there any way to correct these pdf's or do they need to be reexported with t1?
So far this has been a consistent problem in all of my subjects.

Thank you!

Comment: correcting the pdf is most likely not feasible

Comment: Correcting the PDF might be possible but the PDF standard is a **really** long standard (look, 756 pages) as well as really complicated I wouldn't dare to touch it, the easiest way I can think of is either recompile with T1 or throw the PDF into an OCR program.